# Applying a closure to an iterator

Tags: groovy, iterator

Is there a way to apply a closure to an Iterator that returns a new Iterator that produces the elements of the initial Iterator but with the closure applied to those results?

I know I could just write an Iterator class that does this but I didn't want to reinvent the wheel.

Note that I need this to work without actually traversing the iterator to the end (i.e. this should work on iterators which have no end).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

Lets say you have an iterator like this (which returns a continuous stream of random numbers):

```
def rnd = [ hasNext:{ true }, next:{ Math.random() } ] as Iterator
```

One options would be to write a function that takes an iterator and a closure, and applies the closure to each next call (and delegates to the original iterator for hasNext) like:

```
Iterator mappedIterator( Iterator i, Closure c ) {
  [ hasNext:{ i.hasNext() }, next:{ c( i.next() ) } ] as Iterator
}
```

So then we can do:

```
def rndTimes100 = mappedIterator( rnd ) { it * 100 }

// collect 10 randoms from the stream into a list
println rndTimes100.take( 10 ).collect()
```

Another option available is to use my [groovy-stream library](http://timyates.github.com/groovy-stream/) which wraps this sort of functionality (in addition to other things).  With this, you could do:

```
@Grab( 'com.bloidonia:groovy-stream:0.5.2' )
import groovy.stream.Stream

def rnd = [ hasNext:{ true }, next:{ Math.random() } ] as Iterator

def rndStream = Stream.from rnd map { it * 100 }

// collect 10 randoms from the stream into a list
println rndStream.take( 10 ).collect()
```